# Epi Twitter - reading oauth token later in ajax call?

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

I have logged a user into the app on the site and retrieved their details using EpiTwitter/Twtitter-Async. I then want to process these and others through an ajax call and post a new tweet on success.

Specificially, my problem lies with reusing the cookie, i see they are gettting set but I cannot see how to reuse them in later pages. what function do I call?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the php file that catches the ajax request you can access the cookie information in $_COOKIE. It should automatically be sent with the ajax request.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php